# Python: how to make a class method communicate with an instance method of a parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Theoretically I understand the difference between a class method and an instance method. Now I have a practical case where I try to take advantage of class methods.

Basically i have a mongodb wrapper that looks like this:

```
class Model(dict):

    __getattr__ = dict.get
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__

    def create(self):
        self.collection.insert(self)
```

This is how i use it:

```
class Document(Model):
    collection = mongo.db.My_collection

x = Document({'Name': 'BOB', 'Age': 26})
x.create()
```

Now, I would like to take advantage of the class methods to avoid instantiating my objects. Here is the approach I chose:

```
class Document(Model):
    collection = mongo.db.My_collection

    @classmethod
    def create_item(cls, item):
        cls.create(item)

Document.create_item({'Name': 'BOB', 'Age': 26})
```

Here I inherit from the `Model` class. Then I create a class method `create_item`. Finally I try to call the `create` method of the parent class, but I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'collection'
```

So my questions is:

- How to make a class method communicate with an instance method of a parent class?
- Secondarily, what would be the best strategy to implement these classes using class methods?

Comment: Is `create_item` going to return something? Do you expect `create_item` to *use* an existing instance? Do you understand why you are getting the AttributeError?

Comment: @wwii I understand that the error comes from the fact that I send a dictionary to a method which waits for an instance (self)... My wish is that method `create_item` calls method `create` which will insert the data into the database. This will save me from instantiating an object at each operation.

Comment: Is there a reason `create_`item` cannot simply insert the item itself? - `cls.collection.insert(item)`?  Will an instance ever insert an item?

Comment: @wwii Thanks for the interest. Indeed, when I use this method it works very well. But as you can see, I have a parent class `Model` in which I put all the operations of manipulation of the database. If I reduce this action to class `Document`, what will be the advantage of having a parent class? Suppose I want to modify the way I insert the data, so I would need to do it wherever I have this specialization. Which is not very practical I think

Comment: Can you suggest another approach that would allow me to:
1. To keep a parent class with all the operations on the database.
2. To inherit from this parent class in other classes, while using `class methods` to avoid instantiating objects every time I need to manipulate the database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `create` a classmethod

```
class Model(dict):
    __getattr__ = dict.get
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__

    @classmethod
    def create(cls,item):
        #print(cls, cls.collection)
        cls.collection.insert(item)

# MY mongo.db.collection
class F:
    @staticmethod
    def insert(item):
        print(item)

class Document(Model):
    #collection = mongo.db.My_collection
    collection = F()

    @classmethod
    def create_item(cls, item):
        cls.create(item)
```

---

```
>>> Document.create_item({'Name': 'BOB', 'Age': 26})
{'Name': 'BOB', 'Age': 26}
>>>
```

---

To many unknowns to comment on why you need or want to structure things this way but then it would just be my opinion.

Seems like `create` could be a *stand-alone* function not associated with a class.